# Problema con error 403 solo entre servidores

Tags: linux, ubuntu, servidor, error-403

Tengo un servidor Linux con Ubuntu, nginx y plesk desk.

Con una ruta donde me llegan callbacks desde una página de pagos, el problema es que desde que tuvimos que hacer el server de nuevo la URL del callback responde al otro servidor con un 403.

Pero si tú accedes desde el navegador funciona perfectamente.

Que podría ser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vale, era problema del Firewall de Plesk, he añadido la IP del servidor que me enviaba los callback en trusted y solucionado.